# JavaScript Hangman, place the Letters

Tags: replace, onclick

so I have come quiet far in my Hangman Game, but apparently im stuck with placing the Letters when a letter gets clicked.
I made 2 Variables, one of them is "word" which saves the word that has to be guessed.
And the other one is "hiddenword" which is basically the same length as "word" but the letters are replaced with underscores as you can see here:

```
function checkLetter(buchstabe) {
    if(word.includes(buchstabe)) {
        hiddenWord = hiddenWord.replace(/_/g, buchstabe);
        console.log("right");
        document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = "Great guess!";
    }
    else {
        console.log("wrong")
        lives = lives -1;
        document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = "Sorry, the letter you chose is not part of the hidden word.";
    }
}
```

Now my 2 Variables I told you about:

```
let word = "hallo123";//I set the variable to something random, because it randomly changes on start
let lives = 8; //Ignore this one, its just how many tries the user has left.
let hiddenWord;//and I didnt declare this one yet, because it will be only underscores
```

[Example of what my Hangman looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6gKZ.jpg)

So my plan is, if someone clicks a letter (here a example of my clickable letters aka divs) and its actually part of the word, it will replace the specific underscore with that letter.

```
<div class="layout" onclick="checkLetter('a');">a</div>
    <div class="layout" onclick="checkLetter('b');">b</div>
    <div class="layout" onclick="checkLetter('c');">c</div>
    <div class="layout" onclick="checkLetter('d');">d</div>
    <div class="layout" onclick="checkLetter('e');">e</div>
    <div class="layout" onclick="checkLetter('b');">b</div>
    <div class="layout" onclick="checkLetter('c');">c</div>
    <div class="layout" onclick="checkLetter('d');">d</div>
    <div class="layout" onclick="checkLetter('e');">e</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more on what exactly are you trying to achieve? Are you asking for help in replacing (the left-most available) underscore with the letter that is clicked?

Comment: Hey Max, in my Variable "Word" is a String with the word the User is supposed to guess. When clicking the Letters it shows the user if the Letter he clicked is part of the word or not, so far so good. But If the Letter is part of the word, the Underscores are supposed to turn into the letter that the user guessed.

Comment: Have a look at the picture I posted, it might get a lot easier for your to understand my concern. Greetings

Comment: Okay that makes sense, thanks! Is there any chance you can post all of your HTML into a jsfiddle so I am able to know how I should write my answer? Specifically the part of the page with the underscores?

Comment: Hey Max, since the part with the underscores is mainly taking place in my JavaScript I posted you both my HTML and my JavaScript code in one document. I wrote a short comment on what every function does, dont worry its pretty simple and not too long, you can find the code here: https://pastebin.com/Rkf7Mh8t :)

Comment: Thanks again. I've just posted an answer now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay! So after looking at your PasteBin I can see it looks like the #wordToGuess div at the bottom of the image you posted is a div containing x amount of underscores with a preceding space (" _") depending on the length of the word the user needs to guess.

When the `checkLetter(buchstabe)` function is fired and meets the `if(word.includes(buchstabe))` condition why don't you do:

// HTML

```
<div id="wordToGuess"> _ _ _</div>
```

// JS

```
var buchstabe = 'a';
var currentHiddenWord = document.getElementById('wordToGuess').textContent;
var newHiddenWord = currentHiddenWord.replace(' _', buchstabe);
document.getElementById('wordToGuess').textContent = newHiddenWord;
```

So your function would become:

```
function checkLetter(buchstabe) {
    if(word.includes(buchstabe)) {
        hiddenWord = hiddenWord.replace(/_/g, buchstabe);
        console.log("right");
        document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = "Great guess!";
        // Update underscores
        var currentHiddenWord = document.getElementById('wordToGuess').textContent;
        var newHiddenWord = currentHiddenWord.replace(' _', buchstabe);
        document.getElementById('wordToGuess').textContent = newHiddenWord;
    }
    else {
        console.log("wrong")
        lives = lives -1;
        document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = "Sorry, the letter you chose is not part of the hidden word.";
    }
}
```

The code, upon successful guess, now sets the current text from wordToGuess div as a variable called currentHiddenWord, replaces the first instance of " _" with the correctly guessed letter (buchstabe) and sets that as a variable called newHiddenWord, and then replaces the text inside the wordToGuess div the value of the newHiddenWord variable.

Does that achieve what you need?

Comment: Hey Max, yeah you understood it right what im doing but "buchstabe" is supposed to be and stay as a parameter, so the function works with every letter. And I cant really get the .textContent of the hiddenWord because my hiddenWord is not defined yet, am I right?

Comment: If you put the bottom 3 lines of my code inside your checkLetter function inside the if(word.includes(buchstabe)) it should achieve what you need :) I've updated my answer to show you what I mean

Comment: First of all thanks a lot for your contribution! I really appreciate it, but I think you got a small error. You are writing "document.getElementById("hiddenWord"), but can you read a variable like that? It gives me another error in my brower console: hangman.html:146 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of null. And line 146 is exactly "document.getElementById("hiddenWord") that. This is how hiddenWord is "declared" at the top: let hiddenWord; (Its not really declared which is why it cant read it I guess.

Comment: Really sorry, it should be "wordToGuess" not hiddenWord. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I've added an explanation of what the code should do as well @doctorx22

Comment: I thank you from the bottom of my heart! Thanks a lot for your effort and time, upvoted and marked as solution :) I didnt think it was that simple.. wow thank you again ;)